# how to get modified files in a particular folder inside git repository using libgit2sharp or git status . equivalent in libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

how to get modified files in a particular folder inside git repository using libgit2sharp or git status . equivalent in libgit2sharp

```
RepositoryOptions repositoryOptions = new RepositoryOptions();
var repo = new Repository(a_sBitDir, repositoryOptions);

var modifiedFiles = repo
.RetrieveStatus(new StatusOptions())
.Where(s => s.State == FileStatus.ModifiedInWorkdir)
.Select(s => s.FilePath)
.ToList();
```

Here, a_sBitDir is git repo path(for eg, "C:/MyRepo"...but i need to find all the modified files inside "C:/MyRepo/Project1/Folder1"

I can acheive the same using git bash by browsing till "C:/MyRepo/Project1/Folder1" and type "git status ." in git bash but how can i get the same using libgit2sharp

Comment: That's not `c`.

Comment: by mistake added wrong tag i.e. c

Comment: can anyone help here?